# C# console application best practice for pinging a web API over and over again until a specific value is returned

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# console application that will typically be installed as a Windows service but can also be run in console mode (not essential to the question, but just giving context). When the program starts up, it sends a request to a web API for data on how to configure the program. If the data it's looking for is not there, I would like it to ping the API periodically in case the API does get its configuration data eventually.

I'm wondering what the best practice is to do this. Here is a boiled down version of what I had in mind:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var response = null;
while (true)
{
    // Every 60 seconds, ping API to see if it has the configuration data.
    if (sw.Elapsed % TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) == 0)
    {
        response = await PingApi();
        if (this.ContainsConfigurationData(response))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
this.ConfigureProgram(response);
```

Nothing else in the program is happening without this configuration data, so it seems like it should be fine to use a while loop and stopwatch like this? I'm not sure if this is best practice, though. I'm also not sure if I should set a limit on the number of tries, and what should happen if that limit is reached. And instead of a stopwatch (or in addition to a stopwatch), should I be using Thread.Sleep?

Comment: You'll use 100% CPU looping like this.

Comment: Create a timer that executes in a set interval and make your check

Comment: First of all i pretty much like [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) for such scenarios

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I'll try using a timer like Nkosi suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample using Timer.

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).TotalMilliseconds;
timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => 
{
    timer.Stop();

    var response = await PingApi();

    if (ContainsConfigurationData(response))
    {
        ConfigureProgram(response);
    }
    else
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
};
timer.Enabled = true;

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, thanks. When ConfigureProgram is called, I want the timer to stop running and calling the elapsed function. Does that happen because `timer.Enabled = true` is put in the else case? I'm wondering why there's a `timer.Enabled = true` after the function. I noticed `Timer` implements `IDisposable`; perhaps it should be wrapped in a using statement? Or I can directly call `timer.Dispose()` after ConfigureProgram?

Comment: You can call timer.Dispose() directly after ConfigureProgram.

Comment: timer.Stop() is at the start of the function to after each timer fires, wait get the response and validate and later wait 60 seconds (interval) again without take in consideration the time waited in the elapsed function.